# Does popen() add a line feed (\n) at the end of the result?

Tags: lua

I've wrote a small function that returns the result of executing a command.

```
function axsh(cmd)
    local fullCmd=cmd:lower()
    local f,err=io.popen(fullCmd,"r")
    if not f then
        return nil,"Could not create the process '"..fullCmd.."' \nError:"..err
    end
    return f:read("*all")
end

s=axsh("echo hi")
--print all bytes
print(s:byte(1,s:len()))
```

The output always has a \n at the end no matter what is the command:

```
104 105 10
```

*Edit: it happens not only for my own binary command line application but also for almost all OS commands: Windows: "dir", "ipconfig", "echo"... Linux: "ls", "pwd", "ls"...*

But when I run the command separately (i.e. windows command prompt) there is no trailing line feed. I don't need it, so need to remove the last character before returning the result.

*Question: does this line feed always exist in the result of popen()? I can't find any reference to this behavior in the documentation.*

Answer (score 2):

No. `io.popen` just returns whatever string the command produces. You use `echo` as command, which happens to put a newline after the string ( this is what makes the command prompt appear on the next line, instead of just after the output).

You can test it by using trying this:

```
s=axsh([[lua -e "io.write([=[hi]=])"]])
return string.byte(s,1,-1)
```

which does not end the output with a newline.